# CrossWordSearch 2

Tags: crosswords, word-search

This puzzle is sort of like a crossword and sort of like a word search. Here are the rules:

- You start with a grid of letters and a list of clues
- Your goal is to shade in some of the squares so that it becomes a valid crossword, such that:

  - Every clue matches to exactly one word in the board, and every word in the board matches to a clue
- Words in the board go horizontally or vertically
- All words in the board are at least 2 letters long
- The shaded-in squares will reveal a secret message

To solve you must show:

- The final shaded-in board
- Each clue matched to the word in the board
- The secret message

Good luck, puzzler!

[image: Crosswordsearch]

Text version:

```
I T C A S T S I
S C O S T V E E
F A D R A Y V B
D M O S L E E P
A P P L E R R O
I I N O G S A P
A N T T O O L H
O G A S P S M E
```

Clues (in no particular order):

```
 - Almost __ if
 - Private Message, abbr
 - Reddit: he who posts, abbr
 - Process using semipermeable membrane, abbr
 - Fish
 - ___corn
 - Tree blood?
 - Titanic call?
 - Food Inspector, abbr
 - Temporary fashion trend
 - e.g. hammer
 - How much to pay for goods
 - Old bread?
 - Vital human habit
 - Fortune 500 company
 - Lots of these at vegas
 - Suprised sound, plural
 - Needed for a broken leg, plural
 - Many
 - Fun outdoor activity
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blanked out board with clues

> ```
>  _________________
> |     C A S T S   |
> |   C O S T   E   |
> | F A D   A   V   |
> | D M   S L E E P |
> | A P P L E   R O |
> |   I   O   S A P |
> |   N   T O O L   |
> |   G A S P S     |
> |_________________|
>
> AS      - Almost __ if
> DM      - Private Message, abbr
> OP      - Reddit: he who posts, abbr
> RO      - Process using semipermeable membrane, abbr
> COD     - Fish
> POP     - ___corn
> SAP     - Tree blood?
> SOS     - Titanic call?
> FDA     - Food Inspector, abbr
> FAD     - Temporary fashion trend
> TOOL    - e.g. hammer
> COST    - How much to pay for goods
> STALE   - Old bread?
> SLEEP   - Vital human habit
> APPLE   - Fortune 500 company
> SLOTS   - Lots of these at vegas
> GASPS   - Suprised sound, plural
> CASTS   - Needed for a broken leg, plural
> SEVERAL - Many
> CAMPING - Fun outdoor activity
> ```

Remaining Letters

> ```
>  _________________
> | I T           I |
> | S         V   E |
> |       R   Y   B |
> |     O           |
> |           R     |
> | I   N   G       |
> | A   T         H |
> | O           M E |
> |_________________|
>
> The letters spell out:
> IT IS VERY BORING AT HOME!
> ```

Very fun puzzle, thank you!

Comment: Good job for completing in under 30 minutes after posting! Also thanks for pointing out the missing clue

Comment: I don't think there is a missing clue. ROT13(Gur jbeq va pbyhza rvtug vf bc abg cbc)

Comment: @happystar rot13(CBC vf gur evtugzbfg pbyhza) ;)

Comment: @MrSiliconGuy Thanks for making a captivating puzzle!